# What is an easily achievable way to have a fluid crawl or dry at ca. 30 mm/week = ca. 0.05 µm/s?

Tags: time, measurements, flow

Or more generally: How to analogously and automatically time one week per A4 sheet?

I'd love to create an A4 sized schedule for my son that somehow automatically indicates the approximate day and hour of the week in a way that doesn't require a battery or power supply. The idea is vaguely to have a scale at the long side, be that portrait or landscape-oriented that indicates which part of the schedule is currently active. A first idea was using springs to pull an arrow, but I think there is no spring slow yet reliable enough for that (but please correct me if I'm wrong), and I'd prefer not to have to add a gearbox or other complicated mechanism. So, inspired by the currently infamous [POCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-of-care_testing) stripes I thought, why not use fluids instead? So:

What is an easily achievable way to have a fluid crawl or dry at ca. 30 mm/week = ca. 0.05 µm/s? Or is there another more sensible way to simply time a week on paper?

Comment: I'm primarily interested in a physics-based answer, but maybe this question better fits on another site such as chemistry... I'm open for suggestions

Comment: Note to self: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action#Liquid_transport_in_porous_media and http://drgan.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/051_IJHMT_2018.pdf

Comment: Well, there is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_drop_experiment
So I guess there is an appropriate level of dilution of that, that fits your needs

Answer (score 1):

It's not an automatic method, but it'll teach your son to organise things so try this!

On a piece of paper draw a rectangle about 5cm wide and 21 lines down.  Every three lines draw a thicker line so it's divided the rectangle into 7, each with three lines.  Label the 7 sections with the days of the week.

Advise your son to shade in a section, perhaps at (for example) 12.00 Noon, 5.00pm and 9.00pm, he'll be able to see how the week is progressing.

It's cost effective and doesn't require a battery or power supply.

Comment: P.S. Depending on the age of your son, consider making a more permanent well designed one, use counters from a toy or game instead of shading the sections.

Comment: Of course that's one way, but I'm afraid that's too manual, sorry. I wouldn't have asked on Physics.SE otherwise ;)